# Android image button size constraints

Tags: android, image, imagebutton

In my app i let the user take a picture with a camera and then use that image as the source for an imageButton. I use android:scaleType fitCenter to scale the image down but no matter what I set for the max button height the button still doubles in size. Is there a way to constrain the size of the button after i put the picture in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the width and height of the button to a specific dp rather than using a wrap_content

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />
```

something like that